# How does ffmpeg divide into frames EXACTLY

Tags: python, ffmpeg, frame-rate

I'm using this piece of code in python to split a video into frames.

```
    def ffmpeg(self, video_file, fps, start_number, **trim_kwargs):
        ffmpeg.input(video_file) \
            .filter('fps', fps=fps) \
            .trim(**trim_kwargs) \
            .output(os.path.join(self._output_dir, f"%0{NAME_PADDING}d.JPG"),
                    **{'qscale:v': 1, 'vsync': 'drop', 'start_number': start_number}) \
            .run()
```

I sometimes use also trimming options more or less like this:

```
ffmpeg(video_file, fps, 0, start=XXX,end=YYY)
```

Additionally, I have a list with timestamps (starting from point zero) with some additional metadata at certain points. I'm trying to figure out what are the mechanics of ffmpeg of using fps for dividing into frames (for example fps = 1), because when I try to jump through my timestamped log manually with the same "fps", I often get less entries than ffmpeg by 1. It's like ffmpeg always took first and last frame or something. Can someone explain to me how it's done exactly, so I could match metadata with generate frames in the best manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An MPEG file is always recorded at a specific frame rate(*), usually 24 or 30 or 60.  Because an MPEG frame depends on the frames before and after it, the decoder always has to decode ALL the frames in the file.  If you ask for `fps=1`, it's just going to throw out the frames between the recorded frame rate and the frame rate you ask for.

(*) -- Technically, a single MPEG file can include multiple frame rates, but that's less commonly used.

Comment: What do you mean by frames between the recorded frame rate and the frame rate you ask for? If I ask for fps=1 would that be actually each second frame? what if a video ends on half a second, would I get the last frame of the video anyhow, does it round up or down in such cases?

Comment: No, if you ask for FPS=1 and the video is 30 FPS, then you will get every 30th frame.  You get 1, it throws away 29, you get another 1.  There's no rounding.  If it is a 2.9 second movie, you'll get 2 frames.

Comment: Ok that is actually how I'd expect it to work, thanks